# UIViewController class not generated in MonoTouch

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, storyboard, monodevelop, uicollectionview

im trying to create a collection view controller in a Storyboard. After adding it and renaming it to MyCollectionViewController i return to Monotouch. There is no created class called MyCollectionViewController (like it works iE with a TableVieController. I am new with Mono and iOS developing. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything wrong. This is/was a bug in MonoDevelop that I fixed for MonoDevelop 3.1.1.

If you go to the "MonoDevelop" menu and select "Check for Updates", a dialog should pop up.

If you don't see MonoDevelop 3.1.1 as an available update, try changing the update channel to "Beta" instead of "Stable" (top-left corner of the dialog).

MonoDevelop 3.1.1 should be going into the Stable channel soon.